# Split a KV<K,V> PCollection into multiple PCollections

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Hi after performing a group by key on a KV Pcollection, I need to:-
1) Make every element in that PCollection a separate individual PCollection. 
2) Insert the records in those individual PCollections into a BigQuery Table.
Basically my intention is to create a dynamic date partition in the BigQuery table.
How can I do this?
An example would really help.

Comment: I've tried partitioning but was not able to generate PCollections out of them and I could had used Side Outputs but since we have to predeclare Tuple Tags I did not consider doing it because depending on the amount of data in the data source and the dates of the records in it, there can be N-number of Tuple Tags.

Comment: To be very specific, suppose if i have a file having content:
1 ABC 1991-07-18
2 DEF 1992-08-15
3 FGH 2015-01-01
4 IJK 2016-03-10
5 XYZ 1992-08-15
I want to put this data in a BigQuery table by creating dynamic partitions on every distinct date using dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Dataflow to be able to perform the massive parallelisation which makes it as one of its kind (as a service on the public cloud), the job flow needs to be predefined before submitting it to on the Google cloud console. Everytime you execute the `jar` file that conatins your pipleline code (which includes pipeline options and the transforms), a `json` file with the description of the job is created and submitted to Google cloud platform. The managed service then uses this to execute your job.

For the use case mentioned in the question, it demands that the input `PCollection` be split into as many `PCollection`s as their are unique dates. For the split, the Tuple Tags needed to split the collection should be created dynamically which is not possible at this time. Creating tuple tags dynamically is not allowed because that doesn't help in creating the job description `json` file and beats the whole design/purpose with which dataflow was built.

I can think of a couple of solutions to this problem (both having its own pros and cons) :

**Solution 1 (a workaround for the exact use case in the question):**

Write a dataflow transform that takes the input `PCollection` and for each element in the input -

```
1. Checks the date of the element.
2. Appends the date to a pre-defined Big Query Table Name as a decorator (in the format yyyyMMDD).
3. Makes an HTTP request to the BQ API to insert the row into the table with the table name added with a decorator.
```

You will have to take into consideration the cost perspective in this approach because there is single HTTP request for every element rather than a BQ load job that would have done it if we had used the BigQueryIO dataflow sdk module.

**Solution 2 (best practice that should be followed in these type of use cases):**

```
1. Run the dataflow pipeline in the streaming mode instead of batch mode.
2. Define a time window with whatever is suitable to the scenario in which it is being is used.
3. For the `PCollection` in each window, write it to a BQ table with the decorator being the date of the time window itself.
```

You will have to consider rearchitecting your data source to send data to dataflow in the real time but you will have a dynamically date partitioned big query table with the results of your data processing being near real time.

References -

1. [Google Big Query Table Decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators)
2. [Google Big Query Table insert using HTTP POST request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request)
3. [How job description files work](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview)

Note: Please mention in the comments and I will elaborate the answer with code snippets if needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply @paritosh...will try to implement using the first option...the 2nd option is out of question as cannot run the pipeline in streaming mode...
But if you come across any other way to do this pls let me know or maybe if I do will make sure to post it...

Comment: Sure @rish0097 :)